# Why is this WHERE NOT EXISTS() condition returning false pos/neg? (Itzik Ben-Gan identifying gaps)

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands

I am learning Ben Itzik-Gans' 'solution 1' method of finding gaps to apply to a business problem.

**Code  here: http://rextester.com/CPXO58771**

First, you start with a list of sequence values, some that break the sequence:

```
| A.seqval |
|----------|
| 2        |
| 3        |
| 11       |
| 12       |
| 13       |
| 31       |
| 33       |
| 34       |
| 35       |
| 42       |
```

And this query produces the results below:

```
SELECT
    seqval + 1 AS start_range
    ,(SELECT MIN(B.seqval) 
      FROM dbo.NumSeq AS B
      WHERE B.seqval > A.seqval) - 1 AS end_range
FROM 
    dbo.NumSeq AS A
WHERE 1=1
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                    FROM dbo.NumSeq AS B
                    WHERE B.seqval = A.seqval + 1)
    AND seqval < (SELECT MAX(seqval) FROM dbo.NumSeq)


| start_range | end_range |
|-------------|-----------|
| 4           | 10        |
| 14          | 30        |
| 32          | 32        |
| 36          | 41        |
```

**I am struggling to understand how the WHERE NOT EXISTS() filter is working. I went row-by-row to check the logic in the NOT EXISTS() subquery:**

```
| A.seqval | A.seqval+1 |   | B.seqval |   | NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM NumSeq AS B WHERE B.seqval=A.seqval+1)        |
|----------|------------|---|----------|---|-------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| 2        | 3          |   | 2        |   | TRUE- there is no A.seqval+1 = 2                                        |
| 3        | 4          |   | 3        |   | FALSE- there is a A.seqval+1 row = 3                                    |
| 11       | 12         |   | 11       |   | TRUE- there is no A.seqval+1 = 11                                       |
| 12       | 13         |   | 12       |   | FALSE- there is a A.seqval+1 row = 12                                   |
| 13       | 14         |   | 13       |   | FALSE- there is a A.seqval+1 row = 13                                   |
| 31       | 32         |   | 31       |   | ??? -there is no A.seqval+1 = 31, but this returns as TRUE in the query |
| 33       | 34         |   | 33       |   | TRUE- there is no A.seqval+1 = 33                                       |
| 34       | 35         |   | 34       |   | FALSE- there is a A.seqval+1 row = 34                                   |
| 35       | 36         |   | 35       |   | FALSE- there is a A.seqval+1 row = 35                                   |
| 42       | 43         |   | 42       |   | TRUE- there is no A.seqval+1 = 42                                       |
```

1. If NOT EXISTS() is returning TRUE for rows where a value doesn't exist, shouldn't they be included instead of excluded in the output?
2. How is seqval=31 identified as a true positive, when it is returned as FALSE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you're handling the `not` in the not exists right in your stepthru.

Consider the first record 2+1 = 3.  3 exists in the data set.  so NOT exists 3 = false not true.   Set {A} and set {B} get compared on Set A.SeqNum+1 = B.SeqNum

```
  A         B      Exists  Not Exists
            2      NEVER Needed as we always look A.SEQVAL+1
2+1 = 3     3      True    False
3+1 = 4     NULL   False   True
31+1 = 32   NULL   False   True
42          NULL   (never evaluated because of `where seqval < (SELECT MAX(seqval) FROM dbo.NumSeq)`
```

Carry this on to 31... 31+1 = 32.. 32 not exists in set .. TRUE. as it should be.

if we asked does 32 exist in the set it would be false.  but since it's a not exists.... True.

```
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
| A.SeqVal | A.SeqVal+1 | Does A.SeqVal+1 exist in A.SEQ Val? | Since it exists do we return it? | SeqVal | Now Add 1  | Now subtract 1 from next value in A.Seq |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
|        2 |          3 | Yes                                 | No                               |        |            |                                         |
|        3 |          4 | No                                  | Yes                              |      3 | 4          |                                      10 |
|       11 |         12 | Yes                                 | No                               |        |            |                                         |
|       12 |         13 | Yes                                 | No                               |        |            |                                         |
|       13 |         14 | No                                  | Yes                              |     12 | 13         |                                      30 |
|       31 |         32 | No                                  | yes                              |     31 | 32         |                                      32 |
|       33 |         34 | Yes                                 | No                               |        |            |                                         |
|       34 |         35 | Yes                                 | No                               |        |            |                                         |
|       35 |         36 | No                                  | Yes                              |     35 | 36         |                                      41 |
|       42 |         43 | No                                  | Yes                              |     42 | Ignore max |                                         |
+----------+------------+-------------------------------------+----------------------------------+--------+------------+-----------------------------------------+
```

- Now Add one (why? because we know the next value in sequence is the first in a range missing)
- Now subtract one from the next value in a.Seqval  (why? because we know that value exists; but the one before it doesn't)

Comment: I'm still confused about "Consider the first record 2+1 = 3. 3 exists in the data set."         Isn't the subquery saying: "Alias NumSeq as B. Look at each value of B and return TRUE where each value of B is not found in any of the values of A.seqval+1." By extension, doesn't B.seqval = 2 NOT EQUAL any value of A.seqval+1, and therefore returns TRUE because it does NOT EXIST?

Comment: The sub query says, generate a second set of data with the alias B.  compare this to the first set (2+1) and see if 3 exists. it does so 2+1 results in a false.  where as 3+1 results in a true because 4 doesn't exist in set B.  Keep asking, I'll try different ways to explain as needed.

Comment: A different way to think about not exists:  2+1=3.  Is it true that 3 doesn't exist in the A.SeqVal?  No So 2 does not start a missing range of numbers.  3+1=4  Is it true that 4 doens't exist in A.Seqval 'YES' so 4 begins a range of missing numbers.  31+1=32.  is it true that 32 doesn't exist in A.Seqval? Yes so 32 starts a range of missing numbers...

Comment: Ok I think I'm getting there... So my confusion was that set {B} contained all of the values of A... but it doesn't, correct? Instead, it is filtered down to ONLY the values where B.seqval = A.seqval+1, the same way any other WHERE clause operates. So by extension, you can think of the dataset returned in that subquery as: `SELECT * FROM NumSeq AS A
INNER JOIN NumSeq AS B on B.seqval = A.seqval + 1'`

Comment: {B} does contain all values of {A}; but since `WHERE B.seqval = A.seqval + 1` exists as a 'Correlated query' it only JOINS to Set A values having 1 added.  2+1 (3), 3+1 (4 oops missing) 11+1 (12), 12+1 (13), 13+1 (14 Opps missing) etc.  more like a LEFT OUTER JOIN I'll give an example...

Comment: In fact; here's the same results using a left join instead of a not exists: http://rextester.com/DZYY17840  it's just that we don't need any data from set {B} so no need to have the overhead of the join.  In this case not exists makes sense.  if we needed data from the 2nd table, then a left join would be the way to go; but at a higher cost in terms of detrimental performance.  Heading to lunch.  If you need anything else add comments; otherwise I'll assume this got you there :P

Comment: All good. You are a boss. Thank you for fostering a community of learning on this site.

Comment: ^^ Kinder words I have seldom received.  Thank you and good luck!